# What are different web server options on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I recently deployed an app and am using WEBrick, and was considering on switching to Thin.  I am wondering on the different options that exist and are best for a heroku environment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Provided you're on Cedar stack you can use whatever you want - Thin works, you are able to get excellent performance out of Unicorn though on Heroku - http://blog.railsonfire.com/2012/05/06/Unicorn-on-Heroku.html

Comment: This is one slight issue with Unicorn, it's start up time is awful, really awful. I have had over minute and half start up times. This happens on EVERY deploy. This causes Heroku to display errors. Not a good end-user experience. If you want a seamless transition on deploys Unicorn isn't a good option.

Comment: you should be able to fork a new master unicorn process, wait for its workers to start, then switch to that master and kill the old one with no down time.

Answer (score 3):

(Asummption:  You don't mean WEB server (i.e Apache or Nginx), but your application process)

The only real constraint is what you can run on Linux.  Nginx is the proxy that is used by the Heroku stack - but behind that it's up to you.

I've seen stuff running Thin, Webrick and Unicorn with no problems.